# Is it possible to create a virtual editor in an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, vscode-extensions

I want to process lots of files in my extension and editors have lots of useful methods that I need to use to process the content of a file with, but I don't want to open each file individually in VSC.

I have been able to read the files I plan on editing but how can I create an editor?

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`vscode.window.openTextDocument()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.openTextDocument)?

> `openTextDocument(uri: Uri): Thenable<TextDocument>`
>
> Opens a document. Will return early if this document is already open. Otherwise the document is loaded and the [didOpen](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument)-event fires.

That does not imply *showing* the editor, which is done with a separate [`vscode.window.showTextDocument()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showTextDocument) call, so it should qualify as "virtual".